# Opening multiple windows in a Unity build on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I want to use Unity to open a separate window (e.g. an extra window distinct from the original) in a standalone build for MacOS. I have been looking for a while for a way to do this in C# but haven't been able to find anything. I have no clue how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is impossible. See [this forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/multiple-window-game.475407/#post-3272632) by Karl Jones, Senior Unity Developer.

> Multiple display mode is for full screen on each display. If you want to have windows then the best approach it to just launch the application separately for each window and have them communicate with each other via some interprocess communication.